# Access point has no internet connected from Pfsense

Tags: networking, lan, wireless-access-point, pfsense

I've already

- configured my firewall rules to accept my guest network(AP) to access the internet in pfsense
- added vlan (10) for my ap in pfsense
- From my ap settings, i've already created the same vlan 10

Am i missing out anything? Please refer to the images to see my configuration

[Guest Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb0zf.png)

[Firewall Guest Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSfEj.png)

[VLAN interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFBRw.png)

[DHCP Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHdfl.png)

[DHCP Server Gateway for Guest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTnHa.png)

[Guest Cannot Ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg8xm.png)

[WAN Ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmeAA.png)

[Network topology diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBBf.png)

Comment: How are you expecting the ping replies to get back to the machine that issued the ping? I don't see any NAT configuration or other arrangement for traffic to get back.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz im using bridge to my internet for my WAN

Comment: Right. So say you have a device with a local IP address of 192.168.10.31 that pings a machine on the Internet. You have nothing to change that source IP address, so you're sending onto the Internet a ping that is from 192.168.10.31. Even if that made it to the machine you are pinging, a packet sent back to 192.168.10.31 (the ping reply) isn't going to get to your Internet connection. You have not made any arrangement for the packets to get back to those machines.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So you're saying that i have to set the network adapter to NAT instead of bridge to my wifi?

Comment: So I take it that you can connect to the AP, but just cant access anything on the internet... In the first screenshot "Guest Interface"  why is there no gateway?

Comment: @Larryc I've added gateway under DHCP server for Guest, please refer to the last image

Comment: @studentQuestions Something that has access to the Internet has to NAT for these devices or there is no way they will be able to access the Internet without having public IP addresses assigned to them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i've already change the network adapter to NAT, it still does not have internet access. But i'm not to sure how to configure in pfsense web gui

Comment: Why don't you do some troubleshooting? For example, does the machine actually send a ping packet? Does the pfsense machine receive it? Does it NAT it out the Internet connection?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've tried to ping from WAN, LAN , it shows there's internet but not from Guest (AP). Please look at the last three pictures

Comment: @Tim_Stewart vlan 10 is for guest network which is connected to access point

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Ok i’ve uploaded the network topology on the 8th image

Comment: Sorry for the late response, so is this switch a managed switch or a non configurable switch? I don't see any indication of a trunk port for your vlans.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart the switch is a layer 2 managed switch.